# MySQL to display number of entries per hour in a table

Tags: php, html, mysql

[New link - results off by 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8G1Jh.png)I need to echo in a table the number of entries per hour for a given date, EVEN IF they are 0. This seems to be happening but in a weird way... As you can see, the hours column is not playing ball as this should be 0:00-1 .... 22.00-23.00 etc. The total number of result expected is 19 which is also correct when you sum the results together. Got to the point where I now don't know what is happening where in the script and no idea where to start fixing the formatting issues. Any help much appreciated.[Current Result in HTML Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvJ2g.png)

```
// Get list of times per hour for reader 
$sqltimea = "SELECT   CONCAT(Hour, ':00-', Hour+1, ':00') AS hours,
 COUNT(r.readerid) AS tapcount
FROM 
   (
     SELECT  '0' AS Hour
     UNION ALL SELECT  '1' UNION ALL SELECT  '2' UNION ALL SELECT  '3'
     UNION ALL SELECT  '4' UNION ALL SELECT  '5' UNION ALL SELECT  '6'
     UNION ALL SELECT  '7' UNION ALL SELECT  '8' UNION ALL SELECT  '9'
     UNION ALL SELECT '10' UNION ALL SELECT '11' UNION ALL SELECT '12'
     UNION ALL SELECT '13' UNION ALL SELECT '14' UNION ALL SELECT '15'
     UNION ALL SELECT '16' UNION ALL SELECT '17' UNION ALL SELECT '18'
     UNION ALL SELECT '19' UNION ALL SELECT '20' UNION ALL SELECT '21'
     UNION ALL SELECT '22' UNION ALL SELECT '23'
 ) AS h
  LEFT JOIN taps t ON HOUR(t.`time`) = Hour 
AND
    DATE(t.time) = '2016-01-15' LEFT JOIN
 readers r
 ON r.readerid = t.readerid AND r.type = 'A'
GROUP BY Hour
ORDER BY Hour";
$qtimea = mysql_query($sqltimea);

// THE CHALLENGE! Put it in a table!

$hours = array("0:00-1:00", "1:00-2:00", "2:00-3:00", "3:00-4:00", "4:00-5:00", "5:00-6:00", "6:00-7:00", "7:00-8:00", "8:00-9:00", "9:00-10:00", "11:00-12:00", "12:00-13:00", "13:00-14:00", "14:00-15:00", "15:00-16:00", "16:00-17:00", "17:00-18:00", "18:00-19:00", "19:00-20:00", "20:00-21:00", "21:00-22:00", "22:00-23:00", "23:00-24:00");

for($i = 0; $i <= 23; $i++) {
    while($timea = mysql_fetch_assoc($qtimea)) {
        $tapsa = $timea['tapcount'];
        echo "<tr><td>" . $hours[$i] . "</td><td>" . $tapsa . "</td></tr>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: can you show us what result you expect to see? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: If you see the current result in HTML its nearly the desired result. The left hand column should be hour time frames of a 24hr clock but as you can see its repeating the first hour frame. The right column seems to be doing the right thing in showing how many entries occurred in each hour frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not expert on PHP, but your `i` variable doesnt get incremented inside the `while` just add `$hours[$i++]` or just get your label from `$timea['hours']`

And you probably dont need the `for` just initialize `i =  0`

```
while($timea = mysql_fetch_assoc($qtimea)) {
        $tapsa = $timea['tapcount'];
        $hour_label = $timea['hours'];
        echo "<tr><td>" . $hour_label . "</td><td>" . $tapsa . "</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped! Ive got the the hours column correct. Ive testing the values against the database and the values are correct but they are not showing in the correct hour frame.. For example, the 15 result should be between 18.00 and 19.00 whereas is currently in 11.00-12.00... Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the result of your query `$sqltimea` on mysql?

Comment: If I echo out the query result i get "Resource id #6"... I can try running the query in mysql too?

Comment: Sorry I'm fairly new to this, how can i show a picture... The query runs and gives the correct result but with the hours all jumbled up

Comment: Link in question above

Comment: I see the problem you are using hour as string instead of numbers. Can you change the one digits hour to two digits like `1` to `01` ... `2` to `02` ... ? that would solve your `order by`. Or  use `order by CAST(Hour AS INTEGER)` ... or just use integers instead of strings

Comment: So Close! The result are now wrong by 1 hour! Its weird how the right hand column has 1 extra row... they need to shift up one. See new link above

Comment: Shit sorry, can't add anymore links, but yeh the right hand column has an extra row so the results need shifting up one row...

Comment: below `$tapsa = $timea['tapcount'];` add `$hour_label = $timea['hours'];` and replace `$hours[$i++]` for `$hour_label `

Comment: Man you a legend. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hope you understand what we did. Remember upvote and accept the answer